# How can I Chromecast my Photos with the Files

Tags: files, wayland, chromecast

I am able to Chromecast (both with Brave or google-chrome-stable 87) any tab or an individual file to view an mp4, but casting the desktop provides me a dark screen with no discernible image except the mouse pointer.

I could put the directory specification into the web browser and go back and forth from a listing of all the images:  clicking on a JPG file to view it, then the browser's back button to return to the directory listing, but there's no natural flow of browsing from image to image that you have in Files.

I have Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS and Files 3.36.3-stable with Wayland.

```
    /usr/bin/Xwayland :0 -rootless -noreset -accessx -core -auth /run/user/1000/.mutter-Xwaylandauth.IL32Z0 -listen 4 -listen 5 -displayfd 6 -listen 7
```

Any workarounds or other software packages that can cast the images to a TV screen?

If not, then I would need to attach an HDMI cable to the TV and avoid being smart.